# Windows 8 Start Screen Tiles Grouping in "All Apps" view

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, start-screen

Is there an easy way to group tiles in the "All Apps" view? SQL Server comes installed with like 23 apps and I want to group them into one tile.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want, exactly, but it might somewhat do the trick.

Right-click a tile and click the option menu to see the file the shortcut points to. You will be redirected to the Start Menu folder that corresponds to the app.

Here, you can rearrange the shortcuts however you want. You can, for example, cut them all and add a new shortcut that leads to a new folder in which you'd have pasted the previously cut shortcut.

Or, if you just need one of those shortcuts, you can simply delete all but one.

But I don't think there's an option for an "app folder" that unfolds directly into the Start screen. It's probably possible to make a mod for this, but development for Windows 8 is so unpopular we don't even have Start screen widgets yet, so...